# Using BeautifulSoup to populate (and identify) empty xml tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Populating empty XML tags is not something that I can seem to readily find a usable solution for.

Let's say we receive an XML snippet like the following, containing the info of a customer:

```
<TransactionDetails>
    <Name>Jamie Silver</Name>
    <CustomerID>1234567</CustomerID>
    <StaffID>9876543</StaffID>
</TransactionDetails>
```

Sometimes, the snippet we receive might not have the StaffID of whoever served them. In this case, the XML snippet shows the `StaffID` tag very differently:

```
<TransactionDetails>
    <Name>Jamie Silver</Name>
    <CustomerID>1234567</CustomerID>
    <StaffID/>
</TransactionDetails>
```

So what happens when the StaffID is missing is that the `<StaffID></StaffID>` gets truncated to just `<StaffID/>`, where the forward slash is moved to the back.

What I'm trying to do is to insert a filled value into the XML file using BeautifulSoup, but it also needs to fix the incorrect truncation (so that `<StaffID/>` is turned back into `<StaffID></StaffID>` first.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? I don't see an actual question here, nor any attempt at finding a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS selectors are usually used with HTML, but many work just fine with XML. Since you are using XML, we will use the `lxml-xml` parser. And we will use the [`:empty`](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/#:empty) selector. As long as the element has no children and only contains whitespace, this will work for us. This is using the css-selector-4 definition of `:empty`: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-empty-pseudo.

The below example targets `StaffID` that are empty. Then we replace there `.string` with `0000000`. As there is only one instance of the empty element, only that one will change.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

XML = """
<root>
<TransactionDetails>
    <Name>Jamie Silver</Name>
    <CustomerID>1234567</CustomerID>
    <StaffID/>
</TransactionDetails>
<TransactionDetails>
    <Name>Jamie Silver</Name>
    <CustomerID>1234567</CustomerID>
    <StaffID>9876543</StaffID>
</TransactionDetails>
</root>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup (XML, 'lxml-xml')
els = soup.select('StaffID:empty')

for el in els:
    el.string = "0000000"

print(soup)
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>                                                                                                                      
<root>                                                                                                                                                      
<TransactionDetails>                                                                                                                                        
<Name>Jamie Silver</Name>                                                                                                                                   
<CustomerID>1234567</CustomerID>                                                                                                                            
<StaffID>0000000</StaffID>                                                                                                                                  
</TransactionDetails>                                                                                                                                       
<TransactionDetails>                                                                                                                                        
<Name>Jamie Silver</Name>                                                                                                                                   
<CustomerID>1234567</CustomerID>                                                                                                                            
<StaffID>9876543</StaffID>                                                                                                                                  
</TransactionDetails>                                                                                                                                       
</root>
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the brilliantly explained solution and the helpful link!